# Update ONLY some fields of an object in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

For example:

`object1(1) = {
  name: 'Rhodok Sergeant',
  speciality: 'Hand to hand battle'
}`

then I want to update only the **speciality** field, into:

`object1(1) = {
  name: 'Rhodok Sergeant',
  speciality: 'Long range battle'
}`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you cannot do partial updates, you can only overwrite an entire object
- read the object in from memory, change it, and then write it back

Answer (score 2):

This is possible using following steps -

1. fetch the item first using idbcursor
2. update that item
3. call `cursor.update` to store updated data in indexedb.

An example code is -

```
const transaction = db.transaction(['rushAlbumList'], 'readwrite');
const objectStore = transaction.objectStore('rushAlbumList');

objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
    const cursor = event.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
        if (cursor.value.albumTitle === 'A farewell to kings') {
            const updateData = cursor.value;

            updateData.year = 2050;
            const request = cursor.update(updateData);
            request.onsuccess = function() {
                console.log('data updated');
            };
        };
        cursor.continue();
    }
};
```

Check out this link for more info - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBCursor/update

Note:- In above code, i am looping through all records which is not efficient in case you want to fetch the particular record based on some condition. So you can use idbKeyRange or some other idb query alternative for this.

Comment: This would potentially visit every object in the collection when deciding to update a single object?

Comment: yeah right, i wanted to show how to update the particular value. Just added a note in my answer.